# How to send server request when scrolled to end of the listview ?

Tags: android, pagination, lazy-loading

I have a fragment in which I have listview that contains data from server and also have a footer at bottom of listview which also send server request to add more items in listview,problem is that when footer comes i.e. listview scroll end send server request back to back.pleas help me to solve this Issue its a two days gone working on that.

code for scroll listener

```
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        Log.i("a", "scrolling stopped...");
    }
}

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

    if (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount&& totalItemCount != 0) {
        if (!isloading) {
            // It is time to add new data. We call the listener
            isloading = true;
            if (NetworkUtil.isConnected(getActivity())) {
                m_n_DefaultRecordCount = 5;// increment of record count by 5 on next load data
                m_n_DeafalutLastCount = m_n_DeafalutLastCount + 5;// same here.....as above

                sz_RecordCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DefaultRecordCount);// convert int value to string
                sz_LastCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DeafalutLastCount);// convert int value to string /////
                loadmoreData();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please check internet connection !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

code for Load more data

```
public void loadmoreData() {

    try {
        String json;
        // 3. build jsonObject
        final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();// making object of Jsons.
        jsonObject.put("agentCode", m_szMobileNumber);// put mobile number
        jsonObject.put("pin", m_szEncryptedPassword);// put password
        jsonObject.put("recordcount", sz_RecordCount);// put record count
        jsonObject.put("lastcountvalue", sz_LastCount);// put last count
        Log.d("CAppList:",sz_RecordCount);
        Log.d("Capplist:",sz_LastCount);
        // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
        json = jsonObject.toString();// convert Json object to string

        System.out.println("Server Request:-" + json);
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

        jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, CServerAPI.m_DealListingURL, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                System.out.println("Response:-" + response);
                try {
                    JSONArray posts = response.optJSONArray("dealList");// GETTING DEAL LIST
                    for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);// GETTING DEAL AT POSITION AT I
                        item = new CDealAppDatastorage();// object create of DealAppdatastorage
                        item.setM_szHeaderText(post.getString("dealname"));//getting deal name
                        item.setM_szsubHeaderText(post.getString("dealcode"));// getting deal code
                        item.setM_szDealValue(post.getString("dealvalue"));

                        if (!s_oDataset.contains(item)) {
                            s_oDataset.add(item);
                        }
                    }
                    isloading=false;
                    m_oAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    if (response.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Connection Not Available")) {//server based conditions
                        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "Connection Lost !", getActivity());
                    } else if (response.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Deal List Not Found")) {// serevr based conditions .....
                        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "No more deals available", getActivity());
                    } else if (response.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Technical Failure")) {
                        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "Technical Failure", getActivity());
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                System.out.println("Error:-" + error);
                if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                    CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "Connection lost ! Please try again", getActivity());
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "No internet connection", getActivity());
                }
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in the following way :

```
private boolean bBottomOfView;

@Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE && bBottomOfView) {
            if (NetworkUtil.isConnected(getActivity())) {
                m_n_DefaultRecordCount = 5;// increment of record count by 5 on next load data
                m_n_DeafalutLastCount = m_n_DeafalutLastCount + 5;// same here.....as above

                sz_RecordCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DefaultRecordCount);// convert int value to string
                sz_LastCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DeafalutLastCount);// convert int value to string /////
                loadmoreData();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please check internet connection !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        bBottomOfView = (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount) == totalItemCount ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: I edited buddy but i'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do my increasing the default count.

Comment: it works... thanks....and one more thing can I add footer in  listview in onScroll listener instead of where I putted right now